# matplotlib savefig.directory in style file not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, save

I am using a style file to control the default behavior of my figure saving and have set the following in `save-article.mplstyle` under the directory `/Users/me/.matplotlib/stylelib`.

```
savefig.directory   : ./Plots/
```

When I only use the current directory `.`, I get the expected output with something like `plt.savefig("test.pdf")`. When I use `./Plots/`, the file does not appear. I can provide my full `save-article.mplstyle` file if that is helpful. The `Plots` directory currently exists and I can save files to it using commands like `plt.savefig("./Plots/test.pdf")`. When I check rcParams after loading the style files, the correct information is populated in the file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `./Plots/` shouldn't be a string?, have you tried using an absolute path instead of a relative one?

Comment: @kikocorreoso Neither work. In fact, when I use `"./Plots/"`, the rcParams file contains `"'./Plots/'"`, which means that there are quotes in the path itself, which is an error.

Comment: Mmmm, could you check your `rcParams` after the load of your mplstyle in order to see if all is right, `import matplotlib;print(matplotlib.rcParams)`

Comment: Already did and updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file):

```
#savefig.directory   : ~        # default directory in savefig dialog box,
                                # leave empty to always use current working directory
```

This option is used when you work in interactive mode and when you click in the *save* icon of the interactive mode it will use the directory defined in `savefig.directory` option.

Your best bet would be to use `os.path` or `pathlib` to define the directory you want to use:

```
import os

basepath = os.path.abspath('Plots')

# [...other code...]

plt.savefig(os.path.join(basepath, 'figurename.pdf))
```